# how to adjust text in modernCV package

Tags: pdftex, moderncv

I'm writing my cv with `moderncv` package and I have a problem with the `Skype` address, that comes shifted in the right column of the section, rather than be put normally under the `linkedin` url. How can I fix?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
%\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}                 % optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts, instead of sans serif fonts)
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                % idem

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\recomputelengths                             % required when changes are made to page layout lengths

\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}           % page number in "outer" position of footer line
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize Autorizzo il trattamento dei miei dati personali, ai sensi del D.lgs. 196 del 30 giugno 2003} % other info in "inner" position of footer line

% personal data
\firstname{xxx}
\familyname{\\ \\xxx}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}               % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\address{Via xxx}{xxx}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{xxx}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\phone{xxx}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\fax{xxx}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\email{xxx@gmail.com}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\extrainfo{additional information (optional)} % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\photo[84pt]{pic_enhached.jpg}                         % '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to and 'picture' is the name of the picture file; optional, remove the line if not wanted

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\vspace{-10mm}

%Section
\section{Info}
\cvline{Nato}{\small il xxx\normalsize}
\cvcomputer{Cittadinanza}{\small xxx\normalsize}{Patente}{\small B\normalsize}
\cvcomputer{LinkedIn}{\small \url{xxx}\normalsize}
{Skype}{\small xxx\normalsize}

\vspace{1mm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `Skype` in a separate line like

```
\cventry{Skype}{\small \url{xxx}\normalsize}{}{}
```

Here is your code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
%\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}                 % optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts, instead of sans serif fonts)
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                % idem

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\recomputelengths                             % required when changes are made to page layout lengths

\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}           % page number in "outer" position of footer line
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize Autorizzo il trattamento dei miei dati personali, ai sensi del D.lgs. 196 del 30 giugno 2003} % other info in "inner" position of footer line

% personal data
\firstname{xxx}
\familyname{\\ \\xxx}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}               % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\address{Via xxx}{xxx}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{xxx}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\phone{xxx}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\fax{xxx}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\email{xxx@gmail.com}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\extrainfo{additional information (optional)} % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%\photo[84pt]{pic_enhached.jpg}                         % '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to and 'picture' is the name of the picture file; optional, remove the line if not wanted

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{.\strut}{\strut}{}{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\vspace{-10mm}

%Section
\section{Info}
\cvline{Nato}{\small il xxx\normalsize}
\cventry{Cittadinanza}{\small xxx\normalsize}{Patente}{\small B\normalsize}{}{}
\cventry{LinkedIn}{\small \url{xxx}\normalsize}{}{}{}{}
\cventry{Skype}{\small \url{xxx}\normalsize}{}{}{}{}

\vspace{1mm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But linkedin and skype are better added below email, IMO.

Comment: I tried your solution..but it give me an error, that is: `! Paragraph ended before \\cventry was complete.<to be read again>\par \cventry{Skype}`, but maybe you are right, it's better to put accounts under email

Comment: @GiacomoRosaspina `\cventry` takes 7 arguments, the first one being optional. So you need to have `\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{}` i.e., six pair of braces with content or empty.

Comment: Ok, I fixed. A last thing, I noted that the `cventry` command puts default a dot at the end of the line. There's the possibility to romove it? Anyway, thanks for the answer

Comment: @GiacomoRosaspina Add `\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{.\strut}{\strut}{}{}` as in the edited answer.